# Pentaho Adding summary rows

Tags: pentaho, transformation

Any idea how to summarize data in a Pentaho transformation and then insert the summary row directly under the group being summarized.

I can use a Group By step and get a summarised result stream having one row per key field, but what I want is each sorted group written to the output and the summary row inserted underneath, thus preserving the input.

In the Group By, you can do 'Include all Rows', but this just appends the summary fields to the end of each existing row. It does not create new summary rows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To get the summary rows to appear under the group by blocks you have to use some tricks, such as introducing a numeric "order" field, setting the value of the original data to 1 and the sub totals rows to 2.

Also in the group-by/ sub-totals stream, I am generating a sum field, say "subtotal". You have to make sure to also include this as a blank in your regular stream or else the metadata will be divergent and the final merge will not work.

Here is the best explanation I have found for this pattern:

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/pentaho-data-integration-4-working-complex-data-flows

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy the rows too a different stream, and then merge or join them again, to make it a separate row.

Comment: Thanks Bolav, i have tried using merge/join and still it keeps trying to merge the row data - I cant seem to be able to say - add the rows separately. It takes the key of each stream and appends the summary row data as fields in the original rows.

Comment: Just join the streams, and it will be a different row.